# Discrepancies when executing a command in Rails controller vs Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell

I am trying to run the `df` command to display statistics of the disks which are attached to my server. However, it always returns the size of the disk as 0. If I run the same command in the rails console within the production environment, it returns the size of the disk.

Here's how my code is structured,

```
class Disk
  def self.metrics
    `df -h`
  end
end
```

And this is how I call it in the controller,

```
 class DiskController
   def metrics
     @metrics = Disk.metrics
   end
 end
```

But it always returns nil when I try to see the result in the view. The same command however works in the Rails console.

I've tried using `system`, `POPEN` but everything returns the same result.

Also, the same thing works in development (Mac OSX) but not in production (Linux Ubuntu).

Comment: Do you have the `df` program installed on your production machine? Sometimes these things aren't in your `ENV['PATH']` so you might have to spell it out. Usually that's something like `/usr/bin/df` but you never know where it might be hiding on some setups.

Comment: But the same command works in the same environment in Rails console. I do `RAILS_ENV=production rails c` on the Ubuntu machine, and execute the command. Everything works then.

Comment: Might it be an issue with the user account that the rails application is running under. Your environment variables like `PATH` will likely be different in rails console if so, and thus why the command works in rails console.

Comment: How do I figure out what user my Rails app vs console is running under?

Comment: can you provide valid and invalid outputs?

Comment: Putting `ENV['PATH']` in a view can give you a hint, but like I said, specifying the full path should work more reliably. If it doesn't work then, there's a chance you have to deal with some `selinux` related permission problems which can be annoying unless you can just turn it off.

Comment: The output that I'm facing now is an empty string. The df command just doesn't seem to execute in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Your console is running under the user you have logged in. Your Rails app is running under the user, dedicated to run your web server. I believe call to `whoami` from within the controller code will show the user name. This user is likely to be restricted to run `df` command. Though this is not recommended, the possible solution would be to grant this user to execute `df` command (via `/etc/sudoers`.)

I would go with another approach, though. I would add a cron job, that will execute `df -h` on behalf of any permitted user and put the output inside some text file within your project tree. The controller might then read this file to show the disk usage info.

I understand that the information might be slightly obsolete, but since one might execute the cron job each, say, minute, it should be acceptable. The advantage of this approach would be that web server still won’t have an access to system commands.

Comment: Thanks for that. I just tried it and unfortunately the whoami command is not printing out anything when I try it in the controller. However in the console I get the right user. :(